# ¿Cuáles son las formas impersonales?

Tags: voz-pasiva, oraciones-impersonales, voz-activa, lenguaje-académico

Disculpen si el título de la pregunta no es lo que expreso en el cuerpo, por favor las sugerencias son válidas.

Estoy haciendo revisión de tesis de grado, hay diversos criterios, sobre todo si son tesis en inglés o en español, de si se deben escribir en forma impersonal o no, tengo esa duda pero no es lo que me apura ahora.

Mi duda real es ¿cuáles son las formas impersonales?

Sé, a lo mejor es un error, que si hablo con gerundios NO es una forma impersonal, por ejemplo:

> estaba trabajando en,

Pero la duda me salta con los participios, por ejemplo, en vez de decir *he trabajado* o *se ha trabajado*, decir *se trabajó*, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que tu confusión comienza con la terminología. **Impersonal** es una clase de construcción verbal. En esta construcción, el verbo es conjugado en la tercera persona del singular y va acompañado del pronombre *se*.

> *Se come muy bien aquí.*
>   *Ya no se respeta a los ancianos.*

Hay una construcción muy parecida pero con otro sentido, la **pasiva refleja**, como en

> *El desayuno se sirve a las 8:00.*
>   *Estas casas se construyeron a finales del siglo XX.*

La construcción impersonal sirve para afirmaciones generales. La pasiva refleja es una de las formas de la voz pasiva en español (la otra es la **pasiva perifrástica**, que funciona como la del inglés, con el verbo *ser* + participio). [¿[Cómo diferenciarlas](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables)?]

**Los participios pasivos no son impersonales.** Se usan en diferentes tipos de frases y éstas pueden ser impersonales o no. Por ejemplo:

1. *He trabajado* es el verbo *trabajar* en la primera persona del singular del tiempo pretérito perfecto del modo indicativo. Es una frase personal.
2. *Se ha trabajado* es el verbo *trabajar* en la forma impersonal del pretérito perfecto del indicativo.
3. *Se trabajó* es el verbo *trabajar* en la forma impersonal del pretérito indefinido del indicativo.

Al escribir formalmente (por ejemplo, una tesis) a veces se prefiere usar la voz pasiva o la construcción impersonal en vez de utilizar la primera persona. En vez de decir *«yo hice esto, yo observé aquello»*, se dice *«se hizo esto, se observó aquello»*. Ambas formas están bien, pero a veces existen normas de estilo que hay que respetar.

Comment: creo que tu respuesta es la mas completa, es que en mi trabajo estamos revisando tesis y teníamos el debate, el estilo es que hay que escribirlas de forma impersonal, pero a mi me causa duda de que tu ejemplo **3** es como hay que ponerlo, y que en la forma **2** no sería correcta porque tiene participio.

Comment: Es que el uso del participio no cambia nada. El participio en el ejemplo 2 es parte de la conjugación del verbo. La única diferencia entre los ejemplos 2 y 3 es el tiempo verbal, pero ambos ejemplos son impersonales.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are pretty good. I'll only try so summarise the key idea:

> Impersonal means that the subject doesn't exist, or it is not a person.

That's the key. So gerundives and participles don't have too much to do with this tpic. The key is about the subject.

You say `estaba trabajando en`, but that sentence has a subject, which is `yo`, which is not impersonal.

The way to do it is like this

1. Change all "yo" or "nosotros" for "constructions with impersonal or passive se"

For example:

> Medimos los datos → Se midieron los datos.

2. Try to use items as subjects

> Los datos fueron medidos.
>   El programa muestra los datos.

In sum, avoid using people to be subjects when possible. This is all, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido bien la pregunta pero creo que sé a lo que te refieres.

Mi tesis estaba relacionada con la informática. Cuando explicas algo lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

1. Instala el programa
2. Haz click en el menú "Archivo" y elige "Nuevo"

O puedes hacerlo de forma impersonal:

1. El programa debe ser instalado
2. Al hacer click en el menú "Archivo" se debe elegir "Nuevo"

La segunda forma es más formal y apropriada para una tesis.

Comment: me refiero a los participios, ado, ido, to, so, cho, que no se si hablando con ellos es personal o impersonal, por ejemplo: he trabajado

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta complementaria a la respuesta excelente de Pablo:

En la práctica, conozco las siguientes opciones para tratar del autor y del lector de la tesis.  Ofrezco un ejemplo de cada opción.

#### Autor

1. Primera persona **plural** (**nosotros**): En este artículo, *proponemos* etc. | In this article, *we propose* etc.
2. Primera persona **singular** (**yo**): En este artículo, *propongo* etc. | In this article, *I propose* etc.
3. Tercera persona (**el autor**): En este artículo, *el autor propone* etc. | In this article, *the author proposes* etc.
4. Tercera persona (**uno; el que, hay que**): En este campo, *el que utilice el método original tendrá que esforzarse para evitar los efectos secundarios*; En este campo, *hay que tener* cuidado con etc.
5. Construcción impersonal: En este artículo, *se propone* etc. | In this article, *it is proposed* etc.

#### Lector

A. Segunda persona, **informal** (**tú**): Si *preprocesas* los datos antes de analizarlos, etc. | If *you preprocess* the data before analyzing it, etc.

B. Segunda persona, **formal** (**Ud.**): Si *Ud. preprocesa* los datos antes de analizarlos, etc. | (igual que A)

C. Tercera persona (**el lector**): Si *el lector preprocesa* los datos antes etc. | If *the reader preprocesses* the data before etc.

D. (Lo mismo que Caso 5, arriba.)

(Se podría incluir opción E aquí, similar a la opción 5, pero esta opción nunca surge, porque se vería igualito que 4, así que en la práctica, no se usa para evitar confusiones entre autor y lector.)

El gerundio, como por ejemplo "proponiendo", y tiempos pasados, como por ejemplo "se había propuesto", se pueden usar en 1, 2, 3, 4, A, B o C.  La diferencia de trato *no se relaciona* con el *tiempo o forma de verbo* de la oración.  Son aspectos completamente diferentes.

Estilos 3 y 4 se pueden combinar.

Hay preguntas sobre este asunto en Academia SE, por ejemplo https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107259/32436.